# Getting IDL (for TLB) from a COM+ dll when it is not provided

Tags: c++, com, idl, typelib, midl

I have a .dll that contains some directshow filters (COM) with specific/custom interfaces to query.

Most 3rd party directshow components contain embedded .tlb files that can be used for cross-enviroment communication (C# typelib import).

I would hate to have to attempt to manually create the interfaces needed for c# because no idl/tlb files were provided.

Is it possible to generate a tlb (or at least, an idl, which I can MIDL compile) from a COM .dll?

Comment: Take a look at [tlbexp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfzzah2c.aspx)

Comment: Isn't that only for .NET assemblies? [ComVisible]

Comment: No.  You are yelling for help in a crowded soccer stadium.  There's a programmer somewhere that can give you exactly what you need.  The odds you'll find him here are zilch.  Pick up the phone and give him a call.  If he doesn't want to help then that's where it ends.

Comment: What phone should I use?

Comment: How do you know the interface specs in the first place? You mentioned you would hate creating them manually, do you have any documentation on those?

Comment: 3rd party gave me c++ com interop interfaces. I need the tlb so I can generate the same interfaces for c#.

Comment: Apparently they gave you a C++ header file (which itself is a product of MIDL compiler). To my knowledge, a tool which could decompile it back to IDL doesn't exist. You best bet is to contact your supplier and ask for a IDL file, as @HansPassant has suggested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get IDL from a .NET assembly (or how to to convert TLB to IDL) in a command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825734/how-to-get-idl-from-a-net-assembly-or-how-to-to-convert-tlb-to-idl-in-a-comma)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible to reverse engineer/disassemble IDL (or something very close to it).  What you need to do is give yourself a new C++ Console Project which gives the default code of

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

and then you insert an #import statement underneath the #include statement.  So I have been playing with C# assembly marked up to function as a COM Interop DLL and I have called it ComExample2 and it lives in the same solution as the C++ console project that I added which means I can use a nice relative pathname.  So my #import statement looks like

```
#import "..\ComExample2\bin\Debug\ComExample2.tlb" no_namespace named_guids
```

Then you build your console application.  If you delve into the files generated during the build you will find a file that ends with .TLH which stands for type library header.  So my path is

```
..\ComExample2\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\comexample2.tlh
```

Inside my file is something which looks very much like idl.  Here is an edited snippet to give you a flavour....

```
struct __declspec(uuid("515b1b18-1602-4d42-b743-f1b3c458a0d0"))
/* LIBID */ __ComExample2;
struct /* coclass */ ComExampleClass2;

//
// Type library items
//

struct __declspec(uuid("713007fe-e74c-4fec-b91a-5ef8df279929"))
IFoo : IDispatch
{
    //
    // Wrapper methods for error-handling
    //

    _bstr_t Greeting ( );
    long Sim (
        long a,
        long b );

    //
    // Raw methods provided by interface
    //

      virtual HRESULT __stdcall raw_Greeting (
        /*[out,retval]*/ BSTR * pRetVal ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall raw_Sim (
        /*[in]*/ long a,
        /*[in]*/ long b,
        /*[out,retval]*/ long * pRetVal ) = 0;
};

struct __declspec(uuid("efe233b5-8ab3-4414-855e-1f027e0a72d5"))
ComExampleClass2;
    // interface _Object
    // [ default ] interface IFoo
```

All of this is generated code so that you can script C++ code against a COM library easily.  You'll have to pick through what you need but hopefully that should be enough.

Kind regards,

Lord BattenBerg